# I want to make zip file from the folder and split it into 4 parts

Tags: vbscript

I want to make a vbscript which will take folder from a path and split it into 4 parts   using zip.exe by doing so i got an error while calling the zip.exe . It is working for unzip.exe

Option explicit

```
dim objShell, objFSO, objArgs
dim strPkgFolder, strzip, strUnzip, strTcRoot

set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set objArgs = WScript.Arguments

strTcRoot = "C:\Users\sdeepak6\Desktop\extracted\F025.R22.zip"
strzip ="C:\Users\sdeepak6\Desktop\extracted\zip.exe"
strPkgFolder="C:\Users\sdeepak6\Desktop\new project\F025.R22"
if not objFSO.FileExists(strzip) then
wscript.echo "***ERROR: zip file:" & strzip & " doesn't exist"
WScript.Quit(20005)
end if
wscript.echo "zip utility: " & strzip & " is available..."

if not objFSO.FolderExists(strPkgFolder) then
wscript.echo "***ERROR:" & strPkgFolder & " doesn't exist ..."
WScript.Quit (1)
end if
funcZip strPkgFolder,strTcRoot,strzip
   function funcZip(strAppFile, strzipLocation, strzip)
```

'  dim SHELL, FS, strCommand, strFile, intErrReturn

```
set SHELL = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
set FS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
funcZip = True
if not FS.FolderExists(strAppFile) Then
funcZip = False
wscript.echo "Folder: " & strAppFile & " doesn't exist..."
exit function
end if 
if not FS.FileExists(strzipLocation) Then
funcZip = False
wscript.echo "File: " & strzipLocation & " doesn't exist..."
exit function
end if  
 strCommand = Chr(34) & strzip & Chr(34) & " -s 2m -r " & Chr(34) &     strzipLocation      &   Chr(34) & " " & Chr(34) & strAppFile & Chr(34)
 wscript.echo "Executing the command: " & strCommand
 intErrReturn = 0
 intErrReturn = SHELL.Run(strCommand, 0, True)
 if intErrReturn <> 0  then
funcZip = False
wscript.echo "***WARNING: Zip command execution is failed with error code: " &           intErrReturn
 end if
 Set FS = Nothing
 Set SHELL = Nothing

 end function
```

Comment: What was the error message?

Comment: Try `strCommand = """" & strzip & """ -s 2m -r """ & strzipLocation & """ """ & strAppFile & """"`. What is the output of strCommand?

Comment: Still it is showing Zip command execution failed with error code 16 and thanks for the answer